# get State name from region_id Magento 1.6.2

Tags: class, magento

I need to display a single State Name in Magento 1.6.2 by converting the `region_id`
to the `state name`.

I have the `region_id` and can return the array of all US states with

```
$states = Mage::getModel('directory/country')->load('US')->getRegions();
```

but cannot find a help class that converts the `region_id`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
$regionId = 27;
$region = Mage::getModel('directory/region')->load($regionId);
echo $region->getName();
```

Answer (score -1):

This snippet

```
Mage::getModel('directory/region')->load(279);
```

doesn't works on some, old, versions.
For example, Magento 1.5, file:
**app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php**, line 1026, you can see this comment:

```
//$region = Mage::getModel('directory/region')->load(279); //does not work!!!!
//$tmp_region= $region->getCode() ;
```

and, then, the right code (for this version):

```
$sql="select * from directory_country_region where region_id=".(int)$myOrder->getShippingAddress()->getRegionid();
$tmp_region = $readConnection->fetchAll($sql);  
$tmp_region=$tmp_region?$tmp_region[0]["default_name"]." (".$tmp_region[0]["code"] .")":"";
```